# Angular Router Navigation doent work in IONIC4

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic4

I'm using Ionic 4 in my project, and I'm using navigation inside a function, but the problem with this navigation is, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesnt work, do you know whats the problem with Angular Naviget Method please . here's the code :

```
await this.loading2.showLoading('ifOfLoading')
this.authenticationService.register(value)
 .pipe(first())
 .subscribe(
   data => {
     if (data) {

       this.loading2.dismissLoader('ifOfLoading')

         this.router.navigate(['/phone-dialog']);





     } else {
       console.log('Problem');
       this.loading2.dismissLoader('ifOfLoading')

     }
   },
   err => {
    this.loading2.dismissLoader('ifOfLoading')
     console.log('ERROR :', err);

   } 
 );
```

this line this.router.navigate(['/phone-dialog']) doesnt work.

Comment: 1) what error do you get? 2) is the `if` condition passing?

Comment: I dont have any error, just this.router.navigate(['/phone-dialog']) doesnt work